# Provisioning profiles getting invalidated after refreshing in "Accounts" tab of Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

In an unfortunately frustrating loop here. This issue started occurring in Xcode 5 about a month ago and I have just been dealing with it hoping that it would go away with Xcode 6 but I'm still seeing it happen in the current App store release of Xcode 6.

When visiting the "Accounts" tab in Xcode, then tapping on an account and clicking the "refresh" button to download the provisioning profiles for that user, instead they all get invalidated. Then I have to go into the developer portal and manually regenerate each one. The only way to get the valid profiles is to download each one manually from the developer portal onto each of our machines which is not ideal. Is there a reason this is happening that I'm missing? I've never had this issue before. If it matters, these are not the default team profiles, we made and manage our own.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to have resolved itself for us. The only thing I really did was reset all local provisioning profiles by deleting them from `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`. Not sure if that made the difference but I suspected there may have been some duplicate profiles in there somehow causing other issues and this one seemed to be resolved too. If someone has a definitive answer, you're still welcome to post it here.