# iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile invalidates itself when new devices are added

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I've got a Distribution Provisioning Profile I use for distributing my application to QA testers via AdHoc builds / HockeyApp. I'm also part of a team of other developers working on other apps, and they have their own QA teams.

Whenever someone else adds a device to the Apple Developer Member Center (previously the "Provisioning Portal") located at https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action , the Distribution Provisioning Profile becomes Invalid.

To make the profile valid again, I must open up the profile and include all of the newly added devices in the profile, then re-download it.

This is all fine, but it seems unnecessary. My Distribution Provisioning Profile should only need the devices of my app's testers linked to it, not the devices others have added for their own testing purposes.

Does anyone have any information / links to documentation on why this happens (searches only seem to bring up the common issues with provisioning profiles in general that people always run into when starting out), and whether or not there is a way to get around it?

Thanks, 
- Adam

Comment: It has been my experience that you don't have to do all that manually — you can just click on "Fix issue" in Xcode when it pesters you with the signing error.

Comment: @MarkoNikolovski I've always had issues with Xcode's automated provisioning functionality. Thanks for the option though, I'll look into it the next time this pops up.

Comment: Also you can refresh all profiles via XCode menu Preferences -> Accounts then choose your team account and press refresh button

Comment: possible duplicate of [Provisioning profiles getting invalidated after refreshing in "Accounts" tab of Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941913/provisioning-profiles-getting-invalidated-after-refreshing-in-accounts-tab-of)

Comment: I have seen the same problem, except that the provisioning profile does not get marked as invalid on the portal. Instead when I try to use it to sign an AdHoc build I get an error that some devices are not added to the profile.

Comment: @JAL Looks unrelated to me.